# Do I need to send data to Elasticsearch that I don't need for answering search requests?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a client with `name`, `email`, `company` attributes and I only need to search the `name` and `email` attributes.

Do I still need to send `company` attribute to elasticsearch and set `index` to `false`? or just send the required attributes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically you would just index the entire document here. unless you have a massive data set (ie TBs), then the amount of savings you have would be minimal

and, from experience, there's a likely chance that someone will come along and ask to now search the company field, which means you will need to reindex everything to allow that

that said, yes you can definitely take that approach

Comment: Thanks Mark, I forgot to mention that I'm using edge-ngram tokenizer for the required fields, so don't you think indexing unrequired fields with the same tokenizer for future use is a bit too much in this case? btw the data set isn't that massive at all.

Comment: ok, yes that might be overkill. but keep it indexed anyway, it can't hurt